# IBKR IbApi connection does not drop / disconnect after receiving fundamentalData information

Tags: python, blocking, ib-api

the connection never drops, I have tried pretty much everything or so I think:

```
import xmltodict
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *
import time
import threading
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.fundamental_data = {}

    def fundamentalData(self, reqId: int, data: str):
        self.fundamental_data[reqId] = data
        print(data)

    def fundamentalDataEnd(self, reqId: int):
        self.disconnect()

    def run_client(self):
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = "AAPL"
        contract.secType = "STK"
        contract.exchange = "SMART"
        contract.currency = "USD"
        self.reqFundamentalData(1, contract, "CalendarReport", [])
        self.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 0)
time.sleep(2)
app.run_client()

# Convert the fundamental data to a Python dictionary
data_dict = xmltodict.parse(app.fundamental_data[1])

# Write the dictionary to an XML file
with open("fundamental_data.xml", "w") as f:
    xmltodict.unparse(data_dict, output=f)
```

Save me from this horrible ibkr api !

Thanks.

I tried blocking and async methods but both result in the same way with the connection hanging.

Answer (score 0):

okay I found the answer by browsing the client.py lib; call the follwing function after the method fundamentalData:

```
    def fundamentalData(self, reqId: int, data: str):
    self.fundamental_data[reqId] = data
    print(data)
    self.cancelFundamentalData(reqId)
```